# Bluetooth can't hold connection for more than a few seconds

Tags: bluetooth

My brand new Raspberry Pi 3 Model B V1.2 can't stay connected to my OBD-II Bluetooth adapter for more than three seconds before disconnecting.
I've tried removing and adding it back to no avail.
I've run upgrade, dist-upgrade, and rpi-update.

Could someone please assist? Logs from connection below.
Seems like this is the error I'm getting.

```
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.NotAvailable
```

Thanks!

```
pi@choppy:~ $ bluetoothctl
[NEW] Controller B8:27:EB:76:4C:F8 choppy [default]
[NEW] Device 00:1D:A5:00:11:CE OBDII
[bluetooth]# power on
Changing power on succeeded
[bluetooth]# agent on
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# connect 00:1D:A5:00:11:CE
Attempting to connect to 00:1D:A5:00:11:CE
[CHG] Device 00:1D:A5:00:11:CE Connected: yes
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.NotAvailable
[bluetooth]# info 00:1D:A5:00:11:CE
Device 00:1D:A5:00:11:CE
    Name: OBDII
    Alias: OBDII
    Class: 0x001f00
    Paired: yes
    Trusted: yes
    Blocked: no
    Connected: yes
    LegacyPairing: yes
    UUID: Serial Port               (00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
[CHG] Device 00:1D:A5:00:11:CE Connected: no
[bluetooth]# info 00:1D:A5:00:11:CE
Device 00:1D:A5:00:11:CE
    Name: OBDII
    Alias: OBDII
    Class: 0x001f00
    Paired: yes
    Trusted: yes
    Blocked: no
    Connected: no
    LegacyPairing: yes
    UUID: Serial Port               (00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
```

Comment: What are you powering the Pi with? And are you using the built in Wi-Fi at the same time?

Comment: Ah! It seems like I'm an entire amp off of what I need from my power supply! That'd do it. Let me go out and buy a proper 2.5A 5V power supply today and get back to this thread. Thank you!

Comment: Update! No dice. I got a 2.4A 5V power supply, and it still cannot connect for more than a few seconds. Do you think the bluetooth chip is faulty?

Comment: Looks like the bluetooth chip is _not_ faulty! I attempted to replicate the process with an identical Pi3B and got the exact same error. Maybe I'll try another OS that isn't Raspbian? The OBD-II connects just fine with my laptop, so maybe a driver issue? What do you think?

Comment: Could you please confirm for me that your testing the Bluetooth with the Wi-Fi disabled?

Comment: I've been very busy over the last few days. I'll get back to you on this in a bit.